# How to store incoming result as an id to a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, nsdictionary, facebook-ios-sdk

So I'm making a facebook request for some data using the Facebook SDK for iOS. I get a response in the method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSLog(@"Result is: %@", result);
    //How to save this data in a NSDictionary (or some other data structure)
}
```

Can anyone help me by explaining how to save this to a NSDictionary so that it is easy to get what i need from the result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need a key and the value of the object. For instance in a `NSMutableDictionary`:

> [myDictionary setObject:result forKey:@"myKey"];

---

You should be aware of where exactly you are going to store, if it makes senses and what consequences does it bring to your architecture. The above answer was just a quick way to answer your question.